# How to select two properties from a single object in a single line of code

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JS object like

```
    let values={
    
    a:'of',
    b:'ASD',
    c:'Kleck',
   };
```

now I want to set the value of a as undefined, so I would do

```
values.a = undefined
```

but if I want to make the value of both a and b undefined together what  I would do?  Using '.' Notation?

Comment: I've no clue what is asked here. Do you need a single line `values.a = values.b = undefined;`?

Comment: Oh, now it makes sense, there were missing words

Comment: `values.a = undefined; values.b = undefined;` or `[ 'a', 'b' ].forEach(member => values[member] = undefined);`

Comment: @Teemu yeah kinda same but cannot i use AND operator in any way possible

Comment: No, you can't, you need an assignment for both of the values, in a way or another. mplungjan has shown an alternative for a simple assignment in their ansewer.

Comment: Third way would be `Object.assign(values, {a: undefined, b: undefined});`, but this and the spread operator won't work in old browsers.

Comment: You can write an expression `(values.a = x) && (values.b = y);`, but `x` must have a truthy value, because `&&` is lazily evaluated. Also, the intention of the expression is not clear, thus it should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the object using the spread operator

```js
let values = {
  a: 'of',
  b: 'ASD',
  c: 'Kleck',
};

values = { ...values, ...{ a: undefined, b: undefined } };
console.log(values)
```

or directly access the members using dot notation

```js
let values = {
  a: 'of',
  b: 'ASD',
  c: 'Kleck',
};

values.a = values.b = undefined;
console.log(values)
```